# apexPages.addmessage not dispalying in vf page

Tags: visualforce

ApexPages.addmessage not displaying when called from Button in vfpage , but error is displaying in debug logs . How to acheive this

Comment: Can you please post your code here. Please check if you are using reRender tag for button. If you are using it add pageMessage tag's id to reRender tag

Comment: @Navya add the code you have done if possible & also show the error message!!!

Answer (score 1):

For messages to display, you must have [`apex:pageMessages`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) somewhere on your Visualforce page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sObjName == 'Account')
{
    system.debug('rightValuescontacts' + rightValuescontacts);
    if(rightValuescontacts.size() > 0 && rightValuesusers.size() > 0)
    {
        system.debug('m' + m);
        update m;
        system.debug('m' + m);
    }
    else
    {
        system.debug('rightValuescontacts new' + rightValuescontacts);
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'select atleast one Customer Attendee and one Internal Attendee'));  

    }
    system.debug('m.Meeting_Date__c old' + m.Meeting_Date__c);
    if(m.Meeting_Date__c > system.today())
    {
        system.debug('m.Meeting_Date__c old' + m.Meeting_Date__c);
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You cannot create a MOM for a future date code')); 
        system.debug('m.Meeting_Date__c new' + m.Meeting_Date__c);
    }
    else
    {
        system.debug('rightValuescontacts' + rightValuescontacts);
        if(rightValuescontacts.size() == 0)
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Customer Attendee contact'));
            system.debug('rightValuesusers' + rightValuesusers);
        if(rightValuesusers.size() == 0)
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Internal Attendee'));
    }
}
```

Comment: below Error is  not displaying in vf page ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You cannot create a MOM for a future date code'));

Comment: This should be an [edit to your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/288101/edit) instead of an answer.